# Getting Data from JSON to Dictionary Swift 3

Tags: json, xml, swift, parsing, dictionary

Im trying to have a dictionary with some JSON values but i just can't get those values.

I have an XML that prints in the console like this:

```
Optional(<DocumentElement>  <QRCode>    <QRCodeID>1</QRCodeID>    <Description>Some Data</Description>    <Latitude>Some Data</Latitude>    <Length>Some Data</Longitud>    <Length>Some Data</LongDescription>  </QRCode></DocumentElement>)
```

Then i parse it to JSON using a library which prints out like this:

```
["DocumentElement": {
QRCode =     {
    Description = "Some Data";
    Latitude = "Some Data";
    LongDescription = "Some Data";
    Length = "Some Data";
    QRCodeID = 1;
};
}]
```

And this is the code im using with SwiftyJSON and it does not bring anything:

```
let json = JSON(data)
  if let description = json[0]["DocumentElement"]["QRCode"]["Description"].string 
{
  print(description)
}
```

Comment: XML is not JSON.

Comment: The result is not an array, it's a dictionary.

Comment: After let json = JSON(data) print this json to check an output